# Not receiving JSON data from Microsoft FaceAPI

Tags: c#, wpf, http, wpf-controls, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to get JSON data from a picture using [Microsoft's FaceAPI](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236). I am receiving a StatusCode OK, but am not getting anything significant back. I have verified that the MemoryStream has the right data (which I am getting from an Image control) by saving it to a file.

```
    private async Task<string> GetJSON()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

        // Request headers
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "mykey");

        // Request parameters
        queryString["returnFaceId"] = "true";
        queryString["returnFaceLandmarks"] = "false";
        var uri = "https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v1.0/detect?" + queryString;

        HttpResponseMessage response;

        // Request body
        byte[] byteData = ImageToByte();


        using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
        {
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        }

        return "";
    }

    private byte[] ImageToByte()
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            videoBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
            {
                var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();

                var flippedBitmap = new TransformedBitmap();
                flippedBitmap.BeginInit();
                flippedBitmap.Source = (BitmapSource)videoBox.Source;
                var transform = new ScaleTransform(-1, 1);
                flippedBitmap.Transform = transform;
                flippedBitmap.EndInit();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(flippedBitmap));
                encoder.Save(stream);

            });

            using (FileStream test = new FileStream("snapshot.bmp", FileMode.Create))
            {
                stream.Position = 0;
                stream.CopyTo(test);
            }

            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to call `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` to get the JSON.

Alternatively, you can use the Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face NuGet package which does the plumbing for you, plus provide C# types thereby relieving you the tedium of parsing the JSON.

Comment: Using the package is what I ended up doing. Still good to know though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not a c# programmer but after looking at your code, method GetJSON is returning hard coded empty string that might be the cause you are not getting anything back from the server after invoking this method or second reason could be your asynchronous server configuration is not working properly thus its returning blank first and doing actual operation later.

Comment: I'm not actually using the function yet, but upon examining the value of response (with the help of breakpoints), it does provide some data, but none of it relates to the image.